# how to release device locked by bcache

Tags: bcache

Today I bought a 128MB SSD disk, installed it, then installed `bcache-tools`. After attempting to access the device I got these errors:

```
root@dev:/sys/block/sda/bcache# make-bcache -B /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb1 -C /dev/sda
Can't open dev /dev/sda: Device or resource busy


root@dev:/sys/block/sda/bcache# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

/dev/sda: device contains a valid 'bcache' signature; it is strongly recommended to wipe the device with wipefs(8) if this is unexpected, in order to avoid possible collisions

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xfef282bc.

Command (m for help): q

root@dev:/sys/block/sda/bcache# wipefs -a /dev/sda
wipefs: error: /dev/sda: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
root@dev:/sys/block/sda/bcache#
```

So I have the following questions:

- Why did `bcache` started to use my SSD disk (/dev/sda) without even asking me for permission? That's a lot of disrespect to the authority.
- How do I disable `bcache` so I can properly format the devices, they are not formatted yet.

This is the output of ls -l in `bcache` devices:

```
root@dev:/sys/block/sda/bcache# ls -l
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 block_size
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 btree_written
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 bucket_size
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 cache_replacement_policy
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 clear_stats
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 discard
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 io_errors
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 metadata_written
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 nbuckets
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 priority_stats
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Apr 26 18:47 set -> ../../../../../../../../../../fs/bcache/b9d9517a-a606-4ac2-86dc-3399e9678381
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 18:47 written
root@dev:/sys/block/sda/bcache# pwd
/sys/block/sda/bcache
root@dev:/sys/block/sda/bcache#
```

.

```
root@dev:/sys/fs/bcache# ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    0 Apr 26 19:00 b9d9517a-a606-4ac2-86dc-3399e9678381
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 19:00 register
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 19:00 register_quiet
root@dev:/sys/fs/bcache#
```

Answer (score 1):

`bcache` doesn't do this. Either the disk you purchased wasn't clean and already contained a bcache superblock upon unboxing (so it may be a returned drive that wasn't wiped properly), or the first command you ran was fishy: It has `/dev/sdb1` twice on the command line which may have confused the command and it already created the superblock and attached `/dev/sdb1`.

To get rid of it, detach the backing device:

```
# echo 1 >/sys/block/sdb/sdb1/bcache/detach
```

Then unregister the cache:

```
# echo 1 >/sys/fs/bcache/b9d9517a-a606-4ac2-86dc-3399e9678381/unregister
```

Now, instantly wipe it before udev reregisters it:

```
# wipe -a /dev/sda
```

Do not be confused that `/dev/sdb1` still shows up as under control of bcache. It doesn't hurt and you can access it through `/dev/bcache0`. It's not attached to a cache and thus doesn't benefit from any caching, it works in pass-through mode until you re-attach it to a cache manually:

```
# echo CACHE_SET_ID >/sys/block/sdb/sdb1/bcache/attach
```

In that case, you create a cache device only, then attach any disk to it (with the above command following this one):

```
# make-bcache -C CACHE_DEV
```